# I found the way to install PyBluez on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: pybluez

After many attempts figuring out how to install PyBluez on Ubuntu using pip3 I've seen many people with the same problem. fortunatelly I found the way to do it without pip3:

1. downloaded the program from https://pybluez.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
2. then I installed this library using "sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev"
3. and finally installed PyBluez by running "pyhton3 setup.py install" in the folder that I previously downloaded.

My question is why I cant use pip3 to install PyBluez?

I tried sudo pip3 install PyBluez :( :(

Answer (score 0):

in my case the install via install script, ie without pip, did not work. I was able to use pip after installing the 'python3-bluez' wrapper package.